# I want to keep .dll specific config file outside the project folder (C#)

Tags: c#

I want to keep my Project.dll.config file in local drive (Outside the project folder), I'm setting config file path this way. but I'm not getting how to read the config file. AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData ("APP_CONFIG_FILE", "H:\Test\")

Comment: The ConfigurationManager might be of help to you. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: and this may be a similar case https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e4dcfbd5-9d79-46b8-8a04-1cc4ae4b0771/using-appdomaincurrentdomainsetdataappconfigfilecsomefileconfig-causes-application-to?forum=netfxbcl it would suggest that the file name has to be part of the setting